# Could not autowire field jdbcTemplate although defined in xml context configuration file

Tags: spring, autowired, beancreationexception

I'am facing an error with @Autowired annotation.

UserService class contain JdbcTemplate attribute with getter/setter.

Every thing works fine if I "wire" that attribute from within context file:

```
<bean id="userService" class="org.tuto.service.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>
```

but with Autowired i get this-after error message.

Can someone tell me how to inject by @Autowired with no need to configure it. Thanks in Advance.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate org.tuto.service.UserServiceImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java:**

```
package org.tuto.service;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.tuto.mapper.UserMapper;
import org.tuto.model.User;

@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        String SQL = "select * from user";
        UserMapper userMapper = new UserMapper();
        List<User> result = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, userMapper);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(long id) {
        String SQL = "select * from users where id = ?";
        User result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { id }, new UserMapper());
        return result;
    }
}
```

**spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.tuto" />

    <!-- bean definitions go here -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****" />
        <property name="username" value="****" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="org.tuto.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: You can find your answer with this.post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868096/using-spring-jdbctemplate-injecting-datasource-vs-jdbctemplate

Comment: I read several threads saying the same: it's possible to autowire what we want. But in this case is not autowired. If I comment the autowired annotation and change the config context file by setting the service jdbcTemplate property via a bean configuration, it works perfectely.